# Correct structure/grammar

Tags: past-tense, conjunctions, perfect-constructions

Which one of the following is correct?

1. The report has been completed. Copies have been filed in the cabinet
2. The report is completed.  Copies are filed in the cabinet
3. The report has been completed and copies have been filed in the cabinet.

Comment: They are all correct. It then depends on what you actually want to express.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct, and why?

Answer (score 0):

All your possible answers are correct and understandable, however the third sounds most natural

> The report *has been* completed **and** copies *have been* filed in the cabinet.

alternatives might be

> The report *is* completed **and** copies *are* filed in the cabinet.
>   The report *is* completed **and** copies *have been* filed in the cabinet.
>   The report *has been* completed **and** copies *are* filed in the cabinet.

Since both independent clauses

> The report *is*/*has been* completed.
>   Copies *are*/*have been* filed in the cabinet.

are short and related they can be joined for a better flow.
Separately, they sound very perfunctory and military, but that may be the effect you want.