# What is the difference between "The task isn't processed" and "The task hasn't been processed"?

Tags: difference

A project team there are a few tasks. The team manager asks for the status of one from them. What's the right answer?
   The task isn't processed/handled.
   The task hasn't been processed/handled.
Which verb would we use in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Is" vs "has been" in English.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16999/is-vs-has-been-in-english) Also [“has been completed” or “is completed”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169904/) and [Correct structure/grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113066/), among others.

Comment: Thank you for information!

Answer (score -1):

It's the difference between thinking of "processed" as one possible status which the task constantly possesses, or thinking of "processed" as a thing which was done and is now over and in the past.

I think it's one of those cases in 21st century English where English speakers take a word that is one grammatical type, and stretch it a bit to make it another.  "process" is a verb, and "processed" is the past tense of the verb, but "processed" can also be used as an adjective meaning "something which has been processed".

So both sentences are valid.

Comment: English has been using past participles as adjectives since Shakespeare (and probably long before him), and it's not stretching English grammar.